# MariaDB INSERT с данными в кириллице из MS Windows console (cp1252) не принимается

Tags: windows, консоль, mariadb, кириллица

Требуется помощь с определением источника проблемы вставки данных в **кириллице** в консольном клиенте на MS Windows (cp1252).

- Операционная система Windows 10 с кодовой страницей cp1252 (North America)
- Установлена XAMPP (Control panel v3.2.4)
- Из управляющей панели XAMPP запускается console
- Переходим на utf8 кодовую страницу `chcp 65001`
- Запускаю `mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -p`
- Пытаюсь вставить `INSERT INTO x_test (`title`) VALUES ('проба')`
- Команда указывает на `'` и находится в режиме ожидания

База данных создана командой

```
CREATE DATABASE `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Таблица создана следующей командой

```
CREATE TABLE `x_test` (
  `title` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

По рекомендациям найденым в интернете дополнительно делается

```
MariaDB [test]> SET NAMES utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)
```

Делается `INSERT` с латинницей (все прекрасно)

```
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO x_test (`title`) VALUES ('proba');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.117 sec)
```

Попытка `INSERT` с кириллицей ждет `'`

```
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO x_test (`title`) VALUES ('проба');
    '>
```

Переменные сессии следующие

```
MariaDB [test]> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                        |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                         |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                         |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                         |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                       |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                         |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                         |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                         |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\bin\XAMPP\App\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Данные прекрасно вставляются через perl script, php script, [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) клиент.

`SELECT` в консоле с уже вставленными данными прекрасно выдает существующие данные

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from x_test;
+--------------+
| title        |
+--------------+
| проба        |
| проба        |
| проба        |
| Андрей       |
| Андрей       |
| Андрей       |
| natasha      |
| proba        |
+--------------+
8 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

В чем проблема с консолью и как её исправить?

Session log

```
John Smith@WORKSTATION c:\bin\xampp\app\xampp
# chcp
Active code page: 437

John Smith@WORKSTATION c:\bin\xampp\app\xampp
# mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -p
Enter password: ******
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 24
Server version: 10.4.10-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE `x_test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use x_test
Database changed
MariaDB [x_test]> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                        |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                         |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                         |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                         |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                       |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                         |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                         |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                         |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\bin\XAMPP\App\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [x_test]> CREATE TABLE `x_test` (
    -> `title` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.420 sec)

MariaDB [x_test]> INSERT INTO x_test (`title`) VALUES ('proba');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.056 sec)

MariaDB [x_test]> INSERT INTO x_test (`title`) VALUES ('проба');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.049 sec)

MariaDB [x_test]> select * from x_test;
+-------+
| title |
+-------+
| proba |
| ????? |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [x_test]> \q
Bye

John Smith@WORKSTATION c:\bin\xampp\app\xampp
#
```

Comment: `chcp 65001` - в общем не требуется... покажите полный лог работы в консоли.

Comment: проблема не связана с мариадб.  это [баг винды](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160929/reading-utf-8-from-stdin-using-fgets-on-windows/38164979#38164979): после `chcp 65001` ввод с консоли обычной функцией (напр, fgets) не принимает русских букв.  хочешь вводить в консоли русские буквы - переключайся на однобайтную страницу, знающую такие буквы (866, 1251), и потом сам (в своём коде, напр, в триггере на инсёрт) перекодируй строку в utf8.

Answer (score 0):

В MySQL подобного не наблюдается... версия 8.0.16, кодировка консоли 1251, в командной строке проверены "--default-character-set=utf8" и CP1251.

```
12.11.2020 c:\tmp
>chcp
Текущая кодовая страница: 1251

12.11.2020 c:\tmp
>cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\"

12.11.2020 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" "-uakina" "-p" "--default-character-set=utf8"
Logging to file 'C:\Temporary\mysql80_console.log'
Enter password: *******
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 14
Server version: 8.0.16 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE DATABASE `x_test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.19 sec)

mysql> use x_test
Database changed
mysql> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                   |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                  |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                    |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `x_test` (
    ->   `title` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.69 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO x_test (`title`) VALUES ('proba');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO x_test (`title`) VALUES ('проба');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.21 sec)

mysql> select * from x_test;
+------------+
| title      |
+------------+
| proba      |
| проба      |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

12.11.2020 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
>
```

Выложите аналогичный лог в своём случае.

PS. Все варнинги связаны с тем, что UTF8 есть алиас UTF8MB3, но скоро станет алиасом UTF8MB4, а нынешний вообще попадёт под deprecated.

Comment: Добавил лок как просили. Не пойму сейчас `INSERT` приняло, а почему не пойму. Но теперь `SELECT * FROM x_test` не показывает правильно кириллицу даже с `chcp 65001`.

Comment: Console `CP1251` прекрасно принимает параметры командной строки в кириллице. Северо Американская версия MS Windows не понимает параметры командной строки в кириллице. В perl приходится идти обходными путями, чтоб добраться до параметров командной строки в perl. Здесь наблюдается, что то подобное и как эту проблему _обойти_ пока найти не удалось. Поискал ответ в интернете и пока решения нет.

Comment: При `chcp 65001` проблема проявляется как описано в вопросе -- ждет закрывающую `'`.

Comment: @PolarBear Команда проходит собсно несколько преобразований кодировки - консоли, коннектора, сервера... вот где-то на этом пути и косячит. Только я не понял - Вы пишете, что кодовая 1252, а лог нагло утверждает, что 437... впрочем, я у себя проделал всё то же и с 437, результат один в один.

Comment: @PolarBear А посмотрите в логе консоли и в генеральском логе - что отсылается и что доходит до сервера и с какой кодировкой.

Comment: Дело в том, что Северо Американская версия MS Windows внутренне использует [active codepage cp1252](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886452/perl-how-work-with-cyrillic-coding-in-windows-10).

Comment: @PolarBear А при чём тут внутреннее что-то? Клиент имеет собственный встроенный коннектор, и шлёт данные прямо в сокет или ТСР-порт. Соответственно с точки зрения OC это бинарные данные, к которым никакие перекодировки во внутренний codepage не применимы. А перекодировка от консоли к клиенту - выполняется напрямую, минуя внутреннее представление (оно же не через clipboard идёт).

Comment: Посмотрел в log файл, там ничего подозрительного нет. Что нужно добавить, чтоб поднять уровень verbocity log файла. У меня подозрение что `INSERT` не доходит до отсылки. Такое впечатление, что клиент не понимает что от него хотят.

Comment: @PolarBear *У меня подозрение что INSERT не доходит до отсылки.* Конечно - он же ждёт закрывающую кавычку. Дайте ему её, и смотрите, что прилетит серверу.

Comment: В логе ничего нет. На консоле ошибка `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`.

Comment: Команда `mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -p < \temp\work\sql\proba.sql` прекрасно вставляет и показывает данные. А вот в интерактивном режиме не принимает кириллицу.